# Postgresql : Convert output of query(multiple records probably) into single list

Tags: arrays, json, postgresql

I want to fetch the output of a query which looks like

```
ID|data
A1|{'k1':'v1'}
A1|{'k1':'v2'}
A1|{'k1':'v4'}

..
.so on
```

into single record(list) like:

```
ID|data
A1|[{'k1':'v1'},{'k1':'v2'},{'k1':'v3'}....]
```

I have tried using array_to_json and similar functions, but no use.

Comment: I think im looking for something like groupby but not sure how I'd aggregate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `jsonb_agg()`

```
select id, jsonb_agg(data)
from the_table
group by id;
```

If your column is `json` instead of `jsonb` (which it should be), you need to use `json_agg()`